# Extracting common keywords that appear in a dataset but do not appear in another dataset

Tags: nlp, extract, keyword, arabic, text-extraction

I have two  dataset:
Dataset#1: a dataset with 26.7M reviews written in Modern standard Arabic.
Dataset#2: a dataset with 16K reviews written in both Modern standard Arabic and colloquial Arabic.

I want to extract the keywords that appear in Dataset#2 but do not appear in Dataset#1 which means I want to extract the keywords of colloquial Arabic in a specific domain.

What is the fastest way to do that?

The datasets are in excel format.

Provide me with some examples in Python that could help.

Comment: This needs more information. In what format are the files and texts? What programming language? Or are you looking for algorithm?

Comment: in python, the datasets are in excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected text:

There isn't enough information, but based on what you've shared, I can recommend the following:

1. Extract domain-specific keywords (**Keyword Extraction**) from each dataset. Sometimes, even a word counter can do the job. There are other advanced techniques such as `TF-IDF`, `RAKE`, or `TextRank`, or even more advanced methods such as `NER`.

   - NER (Named Entity Recognition) might be suitable for you. However, if you don't have any pretrained model, it may take a considerable amount of time.
2. Create two sets from the extracted keywords of both datasets. By using set operations, you can identify the differences.